# How can I switch between two child View Controllers on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

I am trying to switch between two child `View Controllers` on a particular `Container View`. I have a `Navigation Controller` with a menu (`Table View` to make the different options of the menu).

Each time I click an option of the menu I would like to change the child of the `Container View` but I am getting the child above `Navigation bar` and `Table View` (they are not shown but they are under the new child View Controller).

The scheme of my Main.storyboard is like this:

```
Navigation Controller --> View Controller (With 2 Container View, 1 for Table View
                                           and the other to set master View Controller)
                                         |
                                         |
                               ------------------------
                               |                      |
                          View Controller        Table View
                            (id: master)

                   View Controller (id: Home)   View Controller (id: screen2)
```

I have the following code on `tableView` function (in which I detect when an option of the menu is clicked) to change the child View Controller of the Container View:

```
let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController //container

var oldChild = (currentController?.childViewControllers.last!)! as UIViewController //master
let newChild = (storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home"))! as UIViewController //Home

if (oldChild != newChild){
    if currentController.childViewControllers.last != nil{
        oldChild.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        currentController.navigationController?.navigationBar.willRemoveSubview(oldChild.view)
        //oldChild.view.removeFromSuperview()
        oldChild.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    currentController.addChildViewController(newChild)
    currentController.view.addSubview(newChild.view)
    newChild.didMoveToParentViewController(currentController) 
}
```

This code is working almost well. The problem is that the new child View Controller is being shown above the Navigation bar and the Table View (the menu). So it is occupying the full screen instead of fit on the Container View.

Should I add something more to my code or am I using my code in a wrong way? I have searched a lot about it but most of the solutions are in objective-c or does not work for me.

**EDIT:** After searching for a lot of hours I suspect that it is something related with the embeded segue that connects the root `View Controller` with `master` View Controller but I am not able to embed the new child to the `Container View`. The code that I am trying is:

```
currentController.performSegueWithIdentifier("EmbedSegue", sender: newChild)
```

or

```
currentController.presentViewController(newChild, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but none of them embed the segue. Just display the `newChild` on the full screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added the childVC view to current VC's view?

Comment: I hope you read this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html - it has everything you need with clear code examples.

Comment: @Losiowaty I have looked at this page before but I have closed it because it does not look the Swift that I am using. I am totally new so maybe I am wrong and I can use both at the same time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes, unfortunately the code examples are in Objective-C, but it shouldn't be hard to understand them as they are also described extensively and you will notice that almost all method/property names are identical between Obj-C and Swift. You can use both languages in one project, but not one file, though you don't need to do that to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Horst The code that I have added on my question is the full code that I have by the moment. Do you mean to add Home VC to master VC or the View Controller that has the Container View?

Comment: @Horst I have edited my question. Please look it.

Comment: Besides adding child vc, you need to add the childvc's view also, please look at @Losiowaty 's link. in method displayContentController, there is a line [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView] <-- you are missing this line

Comment: @Horst I have added the following line: `container.view.addSubview(newController.view)` but the master View Controller is still shown. It does not change the child View Controller.

Comment: @Error404 Sure. Your "answer" is really just an update to the question. It's sometimes helpful to leave enough of the original question to provide context for any existing answers, but since there aren't any of those other than yours, your best bet is to simply revise the question to reflect your current understanding. The easier your question is to read and understand, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Caleb I have edited my question focusing on the actual problem (after the new code that I have achieved). Thank you for your advise. I will take it in consideration for new upcoming questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the IBOutlet for ContainerView and addSubview to this IBOutlet

```
currentController.containerView.addSubview(newChild.view)
```

or

```
currentController.addSubview(childView.view, toView: self.containerView)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first sentence was the clue! I feel I was stucked into a wall because I thought it was something related about the segue and it was something about the container, though.

Answer (score 0):

Right before you call currentController`.addChildViewController(newChild)`, try this:

```
newChild.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
```

This should display the `newChild` view controller within the bounds of your container view instead of full screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is also shown on full screen. I guess it can be something about the embed segue but I am not able to get it yet. Look at my edit to see what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use presentViewController and I don't think using a segue is right either, those will cause the fullscreen cover.

I think you're originally on the right track, do you need views or viewcontrollers?

For UIViews, you could easily just populate your view with the values you want and then replace your container view with your new view, you can also load the UIView for a xib or storyboard scene.

For UIViewControllers, I guess if you have specific logic in they view life cycle methods, you need add them as child viewcontrollers and again replace the container view with the viewController.view.

Finally you just trigger the logic in your `didselectrowatindexpath` method. Just try a basic example, create a UIView with an orange backgroundcolor and do `self.containerView = orangeView`.

Let me know if this is not clear and I'm happy to provide code examples if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
//set off the viewcontroller UNDERTOPBAR property off. your VC will load in currentControllers view. you need to set the frame of the view that your are going to load.

currentController.addChildViewController(newChild)
newChild.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.currentController.bounds.origin.x, self.currentController.bounds.origin.y, self.currentController.bounds.size.width, self.currentController.bounds.size.height)
currentController.view.addSubview(newChild.view)
newChild.didMoveToParentViewController(currentController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make outlet of container and add your child controller like that: `self.addSubview(self.currentViewController!.view, toView: self.containerView)`

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered but as I see in your code, I recommend you to pin the childview's edge to the parentview's. As below:

```
    child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    child.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```